# Huawei stream S can't send or receive text messages

Tags: sms, huawei

I have a Huawei stream S which is a Japanese version of Huawei p6 . I cannot send or receive text messages . I did factory reset . Help me to fix my problem

Comment: First of all, is the SIM card detected? Does the phone receive the signal? Is your current location considered "roaming"?

Comment: Yeah all of the things work